# Return multiple rows for each successful condition from row using different columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to return one or many rows for each row input. Here's an example

```sql
WITH data as (
  SELECT 1 id, ['main artist', 'supporting artist'] artists, true new_or_old
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['main artist'], false
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['supporting artist'], true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, [], false
)
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN 'main artist' NOT IN UNNEST(artists) THEN "Include main artist"
    WHEN 'supporting artist' NOT IN UNNEST(artists) THEN "Missing supporting artist"
    WHEN new_or_old = False THEN "Old track"
    WHEN new_or_old = True THEN "New track"
    ELSE NULL
  END as error
FROM data
```

What I want the output to be is

| id | error |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "New track" |
| 2 | "Missing supporting artist" |
| 2 | "Old track" |
| 3 | "Include main artist" |
| 3 | "New track" |
| 4 | "Include main artist" |
| 4 | "Missing supporting artist" |
| 4 | "Old track" |

But instead the CASE statement is only returning the value that matches the first condition (as I'd expect with a `CASE` statement).

I could probably do this by creating a `UNION ALL` and appending that way but is there a better way that I could do this?

(Not desirable:

```sql
WITH data as (
  SELECT 1 id, ['main artist', 'supporting artist'] artists, true new_or_old
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['main artist'], false
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['supporting artist'], true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, [], false
)
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN 'main artist' NOT IN UNNEST(artists) THEN "Include main artist"
    ELSE NULL
  END as error
FROM data
GROUP BY id, error
HAVING error IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN 'supporting artist' NOT IN UNNEST(artists) THEN "Missing supporting artist"
    ELSE NULL
  END as error
FROM data
GROUP BY id, error
HAVING error IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN new_or_old = False THEN "Old track"
    ELSE NULL
  END as error
FROM data
GROUP BY id, error
HAVING error IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN new_or_old = True THEN "New track"
    ELSE NULL
  END as error
FROM data
GROUP BY id, error
HAVING error IS NOT NULL
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach (I think it is generic enough to be easily extended to your particular use-case)

```
select id, error from (
  select id, array(
    select case missing
      when 'track' then if(new_or_old, 'New ', 'Old ')
      when 'main artist' then 'Include '
      when 'supporting artist' then 'Missing '
      end || missing
    from unnest(['main artist', 'supporting artist', 'track']) missing
    left join t.artists artist
    on artist = missing
    where artist is null
  ) errors
  from `project.dataset.table` t
) left join unnest(errors) error
# order by id
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Below is slightly refactored version of above that might be of preference as it avoids redundant mentioning of lookup values ...

```
select id, error from (
  select id, array(
    select ifnull(output, if(new_or_old, 'New ', 'Old ')) || missing
    from unnest([struct
      ('main artist' as missing, 'Include ' as output), 
      ('supporting artist', 'Missing '), 
      ('track', null)])
    left join t.artists artist
    on artist = missing
    where artist is null
  ) errors
  from `project.dataset.table` t
) left join unnest(errors) error
# order by id
```

Comment: I think I'm gonna go for the `UNION ALL` approach as this wouldn't be too intuitive for other devs (and myself in future ). Appreciate the help!

Comment: consider voting up the answer :o)